# get_dir_file_info date returned not readable

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I used the `get_dir_file_info` function of Codeigniter to get the file details inside a directory

The function returns an array like this:

```
name: "file.sql"
server_path: "filepath\file.sql"
size: 22055
date: 1581558753
relative_path: "filepath/"
```

I can't understand the date returned by the function. How do I convert it to a readable date?

Comment: date('m/d/Y H:i:s', 1581558753); 
It will give you output like 02/13/2020 01:52:33

Answer (score 1):

use just a simple `date()` function like given below:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1581558753);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a UNIX timestamp. It is the number of seconds that have elapsed since the Unix epoch, that is the time 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970, minus leap seconds. There are many ways to convert this to an ordinary date or vice versa.

**Online**

https://www.unixtimestamp.com/

**PHP**

For converting UNIX time to common date:

```
 date("Y/m/d H:i:s" , 1581558753); //Result=>2020/02/13 1:52:33
```

For converting date to UNIX timestamp:

```
 strtotime("3 October 2005"); //Result =>1128297600
```

or:

```
 mktime(0,0,0,10,3,2005);  //Result =>1128297600
```